# Use siunitx to highlight a table column?

Tags: tables, color, siunitx, highlighting, fill

I am using siunitx to align my columns by the decimal point. I want to highlight one of the columns in my table (edited: make a column have a coloured background).  I was wondering if siunitx has a function for this. So far, I have only managed to change the font colour like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=3.2]S[table-
format=3.2]S[table-format=3.2,color=red]}
    \toprule
    1 &       2 &       3  \\
    1.0 &     2.0 &     3.0 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Which produces this result:

[image: Table with red text.]

It would be really great if someone knows of a soft green colour that will also print ok in grayscale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your solution doesn't work. simple solution, which will also colored fonts in column header, is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=3.2]
                S[table-format=3.2]
  >{\color{red}}S[table-format=3.2]}% correct way to prescribe font color
    \toprule
    1 &       2 &       3  \\
    1.0 &     2.0 &     3.0 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

more advance solution, where you can select, which cells will have content in red:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}           % <--
\newrobustcmd{\R}{\color{red}}  % <--

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=3.2]
                S[table-format=3.2]
                S[detect-weight,% <--
                  table-format=3.2]}
    \toprule
    1   &   2   &     3  \\
    1.0 &   2.0 & \R  3.0 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit:**
from your comment follows, that you actually like to have colored column background in some "soft green" color. for colors please look in documentation for `xcolor` package, which detailed describe predefined colors by name or how to define own. shortly, color you should select yourself, the best is use simple gray as i use in mwe below.

*note:* using colored column doesn't doing well with rules from`booktabs`!

[image]

to have column color till to rule, you have two possibilities: (i) change rule to `\hline`, or (ii) redefine `booktabs` rules that you remove added vertical space around it:

```
\setlenght\aboverulesep{0pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
```

(not considered in mwe below)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% <--- changed

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=3.2]
                S[table-format=3.2]
>{\columncolor{gray!20}}S[table-format=3.2]}
    \toprule
    1 &       2 &       3  \\
    1.0 &     2.0 &     3.0 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. What I want to do though is shade the background of the whole column... I think I was unclear.

Comment: @NicoleAndrew, than please edit you question and  correct your information, what is the problem :-)